# Select random name list from database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm new in PHP and  have a question about PHP and MySQL. 
I have about 150 name list, every month i must arrange all them to new group but must different with last month.

So how can i call all name from MySQL table using PHP and generate about 10 group and make sure the list name not same with last month

[image]

Comment: If you rearrange them randomly, the chance that you'll get the same list is so tiny I wouldn't worry about checking for it.

Comment: What does "different" mean?  Sample data and examples would be very helpful.

Comment: so you want to generate 10 name from sql

Comment: @sanojlawrence example i have 150 name, i want generate for 10 group. so next time generate i want all name will be on different group

Comment: @GordonLinoff what i means by 'different' is the person will get different group for next generate

Comment: @MuhammadYusufAhmadShahRudd what have you tried so far..?

Comment: @sanojlawrence for now i did not find the logic to do like that whether use looping or if else statement or what. i'm very amateur in php

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you have already getting all your name in a list called `$names`.

```
$groups = [];

while(count($names) > 0)
{
    $group = [];

    while(count($names) > 0 && count($group) < 10)
    {
        $keys = array_keys($names);
        $index = $keys[rand(0, count($keys) - 1)];

        $group[] = $names[$index];
        unset($names[$index]);
    }

    $groups[] = $group;
}
```